# Parse filename information into multiple columns in the concatenated csv file

Tags: python-3.x

I have multiple `csv` files in a folder and each has a unique file name such as `W10N1_RTO_T0_1294_TL_IV_Curve.csv`. I would like to concatenate all files together and create multiple columns based on the filename information. For example, `W10N1` is one column called `DieID`.

I am a beginner on programming and Python. I couldn't figure how to do it easily.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import csv

os.chdir('filepath')
extension='csv'
all_filenames=[i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
combined_csv=pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames])
combined_csv.to_csv('combined_csv.csv',index=False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.listdir("your_target_direcotry")
```

will return a list of all files and directories in "your_target_direcotry".

Then it is just string manipulation. e.g

```
x = ‘blue_red_green’
x.split(“_”)

[‘blue’, ‘red’, ‘green’]
>>>

>>> a,b,c = x.split(“_”)

>>> a
‘blue’

>>> b 
‘red’

>>> c
‘green’
```

Also do separate for "." first to remove .csv

At last, create a CSV which can operate by any separator u want.

```
f= open("yourfacnyname.csv","w+")

f.write("DieID You_fancy_other_IDs also_if_u_want_variable_use_this_%d\r\n" % (i+1))

f.close()
```

EZ as A B C